# Dendrogram visualisation with igraph and networkD3 in R

Tags: r, igraph, networkd3

I have an igraph (R) graph object named `g` like this:

```
IGRAPH UNW- 6 5 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
+ edges (vertex names):
[1] 1--4 1--5 1--6 4--2 3--5
```

I run clustering on it like this:

```
c1 <-  cluster_fast_greedy(g)
```

I then convert it to a hclust object like this:

```
hc <-  as.hclust(c1)
```

Checking the labels at this point yields:

```
> hc$labels
[1] "1" "4" "3" "5" "6" "2"
```

Then using networkD3, I convert that to a radialNetwork

```
rad <- as.radialNetwork(hc)
```

I plot it with (for example):

```
D3graph <- radialNetwork(List = rad, 
                         fontSize = 10, 
                         opacity = 0.8, 
                         margin=1, 
                         fontFamily = "sans-serif",
                         nodeColour = "grey",
                         nodeStroke = "white"
                         )
```

But a node named `hc`, and a set of unnamed nodes turn up in the dendrogram. Like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the root node name in the `as.radialNetwork` function to a zero-length string...

```
library(networkD3)
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
rad <- as.radialNetwork(hc, '')
radialNetwork(List = rad)
```

I can't see what your object `g` is without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/4389763), so I can't explain why your nodes are not labeled, but I suspect that happens in either your `cluster_fast_greedy` function or the `as.hclust` function. `hc$labels` should show what your labels are set to (or are not set to) before you get to the `as.radialNetwork` function.

Comment: I edited above to show the contents of `g` and added the output of `hc$labels`. Even if specifying root node, I get unnamed 'extra' nodes.

Comment: `hc$labels` shows you what your labels are set to. They are set to `"1" "4" "3" "5" "6" "2"`. Those are the same labels you see on the `radialNetwork` output.

Comment: But what does the `hc` node and the unnamed nodes on the image represent?

Comment: `hc` node is the root. unnamed nodes are clusters of your nodes

Comment: Yes, thanks! Now I see. Many online examples of radialNetwork have named cluster nodes. Were they likely manually added? Can I visualise the radialNetwork without clusters?

Comment: absolutely... see the example on the site http://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/#radial

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144131/discussion-between-textnet-and-cj-yetman).

Comment: btw... if you want to use your igraph object without clustering it first, you should be able to do this `radialNetwork(igraph_to_networkD3(g))`